# how to improve f1 score for a imbalanced multiclass classification problem, tried using smote but it is giving bad results?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

Dataset: [train.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C6m_xjJUxK40w-OJxFifMnCY3pNOPFOV/view?usp=sharing)

**Approach**

I have four classes to be predicted and they are really very imbalanced so i tried using SMOTE and a feed forward network but using smote is giving very poor results as compared to original dataset on the test data

**model architecture**

```
#model architecture

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Flatten

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(7, )))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

earlystopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor="val_loss",
    patience=40,
    mode="auto",
    restore_best_weights=True,
)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

So how to approach for this problem and increase the f1-score on the test dataset
Any help is appreciated

Comment: The description is missing some infos.What were the F1-scores that are considered bad?

Comment: Also, if you optimize the scores directly on the test dataset, then the test scores won't be a good measure of the real model performance. That's what the validation data is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an explanation of what could be the best approach for your case.

###### SMOTE

- Usually **SMOTE** balances out the data by random upsampling, so even if you have a data sample distribution like **Class A** having **15000 Records** and **Class B** having **200 records** it would upsample the **Class B** to **15000 Records** too.
- Having too many random samples generated from the **200 Records** it self sometimes makes the model very hard to learn and differentiate between classes, since the upsampling has significantly increased Class B records from 200 to 15000 by duplicating it.

###### Possible Solutions

1. Instead of **SMOTE** I would recommend to try [Stratified Sampling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stratified-sampling-in-pandas/) between the train/test and then try building the model on top of it.
2. Having class weights as parameter is another best approach and its present almost for all ML algorithms. In your case for Keras you can [Refer Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data) it could be very helpful.

Comment: I am using class_weight technique in keras, I have four classes as 0, 1, 2 and 3 but many 0 and 1 classes are predicted as 2, I have visualised it using confusion matrix so what should i do , should i tweak the class weight of 2

Comment: Can you provide the normalized value counts of your all classes ?

Comment: 0 :  1446, 
1:  891, 
2 : 344, 
3 : 173